Sound not working on HP Omen Transcend 14
I just got a new HP Omen Transcend 14 laptop and installed Ubuntu 24.04 alongside Windows. For some reason the sound isn't working. A link to Realtek's website was provided in some articles about sound on HP laptops not working, but sadly that link is broken.
The link in question is https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software.
This is the output of dmesg filtered by outputs from sound drivers:
jaherron@skull-ubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -E 'snd|sof'
[    0.030440] software IO TLB: area num 32.
[    0.540445] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[    0.540446] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x0000000055320000-0x0000000059320000] (64MB)
[    0.649990] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Corporation: Windows UEFI CA 2023: aefc5fbbbe055d8f8daa585473499417ab5a5272'
[    0.650008] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011: a92902398e16c49778cd90f99e4f9ae17c55af53'
[    0.650025] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011: 13adbf4309bd82709c8cd54f316ed522988a1bd4'
[    2.459255] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    2.459284] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    2.459371] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.459605] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    2.459616] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    2.624760] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    2.624795] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    2.624803] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.625054] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    4.009336] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    4.009545] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    4.009557] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    4.009850] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    4.010081] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    4.010840] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    4.010851] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    4.010857] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    4.010864] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    4.011054] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    4.013527] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.020604] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[    4.032427] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 2
[    4.032432] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
[    4.035086] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: SOF firmware and/or topology file not found.
[    4.035091] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: Supported default profiles
[    4.035093] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: - ipc type 1 (Requested):
[    4.035094] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3:  Firmware file: intel/sof-ipc4/mtl/sof-mtl.ri
[    4.035096] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3:  Topology file: intel/sof-ace-tplg/sof-mtl-rt711-2ch.tplg
[    4.035097] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: Check if you have 'sof-firmware' package installed.
[    4.035098] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: Optionally it can be manually downloaded from:
[    4.035099] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3:    https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/
[    4.036546] sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl 0000:00:1f.3: error: sof_probe_work failed err: -2



I had this issue, which led me to file Audio driver fails to load on HP Omen 14, Intel Core 9 Ultra Meteor Lake · Issue #4880 · thesofproject/linux · GitHub ... but even once that hits your distro, it still won't be the full fix. I haven't been able to figure it out for my own laptop running Arch.

I don't remember if I had that dmesg output, and what was my error, but I didn't have sound on my hp envy. It is a regular problem with those laptops so maybe it's the same with omen. I resolved it by installing kernel 6.9.0 rc6. You could try it, and go back if it doesn't work. Also did you check what is in syslog file?

I cannot install a different kernel because Windows 11 will break if I disable Secure Boot. Also, where can I put my syslog?
